# Python socket.sendall sending apparently arbitrary lengths

Tags: python, sockets, client

I'm creating a small script to send call records to a server using Python 3 socket library.

Each record is 109 bytes in length exactly.

When I loop through the socket sender, and observe the recieving end as well as wireshark, I see that some packets are far too large to be correct. Wireshark shows that a packet with the correct data is 170 in length. There are some packets being sent that are over 1500 in length.

At times, the receiving end will reject 2 packets of length 59 and 50 (adding up to 1 full packet).

Is there a way to get this to work more reliably?

Here's the method I'm using.

```
def connect_to_collector(iterator_obj, host, port, rate, count):

if count == None:
  count = len(iterator_obj.mylist)
delay = 3600 / int(rate)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, int(port)))
print ('\n[+] Connected to {} on port {}'.format(host, port))

start = timer()
i = 0
for record in iterator_obj:

  if i < count:
    try:
      if len(record) is not length:
        print ('the length was ', length)
      s.sendall(record)
      time.sleep(delay)
      i += 1 

    except:
      e = sys.exc_info()
      print ('SEND ERROR OCCURRED ', e)
      print ('\n[+] Sent {} to {} on port {} in {:.4f} seconds'.format(i, host, port, timer() - start))
      sys.exit()

    if verbose:
      print ('Sending : |{:' '<150}| record number |{}|'.format(record, i))
  if i >= count:
    break     
# Clean up

print ('\n[+] Sent {} to {} on port {} in {:.4f} seconds'.format(count, host, port, timer() - start))

s.close()
```

Edit: There is a bug in the

```
for record in iterator_obj:

  if i < count:
    try:
      if len(record) is not length:
        print ('the length was ', length)
      s.sendall(record)
```

The while inside the iterator was occasionally causing sendall() to be called multiple times for the same record.

I removed that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>
> Is there a way to get this to work more reliably?

You are using TCP here and TCP is a stream protocol, not a datagram (packet) protocol. That means the whole connection is seen as a single data stream and the TCP stack if free to optimize to optimize the transport, like sending some data together or splitting some other data. If you are expecting each recv match exactly one send you are doing it wrong.

If you want a datagram protocol use UDP. But in this case you have to deal with lost packets and packet reordering or duplicates yourself. There are protocols like SCTP which are a datagram protocol like UDP but with the reliability of TCP, but they might not be universally supported everywhere and you might getting problems using it through firewalls.

Comment: This makes sense. Additionally I just wanted to point out for posterity's sake that there was a bug in my code causing it to send duplicates. Will edit in a correction.